# Remove unnecessary rows with different status degree

Tags: sql, inner-join

| OrderNumber | OrderStatus |
| --- | --- |
| 560 | 0002 |
| 560 | 0016 |
| 560 | 0028 |
| 180 | 0002 |
| 180 | 0215 |
| 180 | 0485 |

So the order status numbers represents different status' like 0002 means the order object is created, 0485 means order has been completed etc. What I wanted to achieve is if an order is completed or cancelled, I don't want to see any other status of the order like object creation. I have three tables. Let's call them A,B and C. OrderNumber is from table A and OrderStatus from table C . And table B is the joint table where I keep my OrderNo and OrderStat.

````
   select A.OrderNumber, C.OrderStatus 
   from(A inner join B on B.OrderNo = A.OrderNo 
   inner join C on C.OrderStatus = B.OrderStat)
   where A.OrderNumber in (this is where I need some help I think);```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for CTE to get all the completed orders. Now, you can filter these orders in your resultset and show the completed orders only with completed status.

**Note:** Based on the question content, I have only considered completed orders. You can add cancelled orders also to the CTE, by adding cancelled Order Status.

```sql
;WITH CTE_CompletedCancelledOrders AS
(
SELECT OrderNumber, OrderStatus FROM B
WHERE B.OrderStatus = '0485' -- completedOrders
)
select A.OrderNumber, C.OrderStatus 
   from A inner join B on B.OrderNo = A.OrderNo 
   inner join C on C.OrderStatus = B.OrderStatus
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CTE_CompletedCancelledOrders 
WHERE OrderNumber = A.OrderNumber) -- only incomplete Orders 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM CTE_CompletedCancelledOrders -- completed Orders
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is probably window functions:

```
select o.*
from (select A.OrderNumber, C.OrderStatus,
            sum(case when C.OrderStatus in ('0485', . . . ) then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by A.OrderNumber) as completed_or_canceled 
     from A inner join
          B
          on B.OrderNo = A.OrderNo inner join
          C
          on C.OrderStatus = B.OrderStat
     ) o
where completed_or_canceled = 0 or
      OrderStatus in ('0485', . . . );
```

The `. . .` is for the statuses that define the completed/canceled conditions.